# why is this makefile command running so frequently

Tags: make, gnu-make

I have the makefile below.

Why does the rule for the `data/vix.csv` target always execute when I run `make`, though?

In a [recent answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727296/writing-makefiles-that-are-dependent-on-date-and-or-time/70728608#70728608), someone showed me how to update `last_updated.txt` on 24 hour intervals, even if I was running `make` frequently. As a result, `@echo "\n\n##### updating last_updated.txt#####\n\n"` rarely prints when I run `make`.

As far as I can see, that is the only thing that updates `last_updated.txt`. But is there something else modifying that file? Something else seems to updating it because it's the only dependency of the first rule, and `@echo "\n\n######## downloading fresh data and updating vix.csv ##########\n\n"` is always printing. This isn't great because this is the portion of the makefile that calls a web api.

```
TS24 := .timestamp24
DUMMY := $(shell touch -d 'yesterday' "$(TS24)")

# update data if it has been 24 hours
data/vix.csv: last_updated.txt
    @echo "\n\n######## downloading fresh data and updating vix.csv ##########\n\n"
    Rscript update_csv.R

# signal that it's been >24 hours since data download
last_updated.txt: $(TS24)
    @echo "\n\n##### updating last_updated.txt#####\n\n"
    touch "$@"

.PHONY: run
run: 
    @echo "\n\n####### running shiny app ###########\n\n"
    R --quiet -e "shiny::runApp(launch.browser=TRUE)"

## remove all target, output and extraneous files
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *~ *.Rout *.RData *.docx *.pdf *.html *-syntax.R *.RData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ls -l data/vix.csv` to see the actual timestamp of `data/vix.csv`.

Does it reflect the time you last ran make and saw the `downloading fresh data and updating vix.csv` message?

Or does it reflect the timestamp of the source material, wherever `Rscript update_csv.R` gets it from?

Or does it actually get updated at all?